# Array formula without some rows

Tags: excel, formula

I have a question about an array formula. I want to a formula but not get the values for some rows.

I now have this array formula working: =IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SMALL(IF($H$7:$H$59>0,ROW($7:$59),""),ROW(A1)),1)),"")

I want to use this formula but only show the values from rows 7:36 and rows 40:59.

How can I adjust the formula to make it return only the values from these rows above? The rest of the formula is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First INDIRECT and ADDRESS are Volatile.  Replace them with INDEX:

Your current formula non-volatile:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF($H$7:$H$59>0,ROW($7:$59),""),ROW(A1)),"")
```

Next we can add some more criteria to the IF to ignore those rows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(($H$7:$H$59>0)*((ROW($H$7:$H$59)<=36)+(ROW($H$7:$H$59)>=40)),ROW($7:$59),""),ROW(A1)),"")
```

Still an array formula that must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: thank you very much! This worked for me! I only had to add which column number I wanted at the end of the formula (ROWA1)),1 :) But yet again thank you for your time and help :)